# C# Mem Usage In Task Manager - Looks Wrong?

Tags: c#, memory

I have an app which ProcExp shows as having 500MB of private bytes assigned to it - This is about right as the app does a lot of data processing

When I see the same process in task manager it report 20MB of usage which is clearly wrong

Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing the `Private Working Set` of the process in Task Manager (the default view). What you may actually want to look at, however, is the `Working Set` and/or the `Commit Size`, rather than just the `Private Working Set`.

You can change this under `Vuew > Select Columns`, and selecting the appropriate checkboxes.